# how do you access 'this' control's clientID or just do Bootstrap's .popover() in jscript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

The 'this' I'm talking about is the first argument of createDiv function call below. So it's basically the LinkButton that is clicked.

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="btn_ReportReply1" runat="server" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" Text="ReportReply" OnClientClick='<%# String.Format("createDiv(this," + Eval("UniqueNo") +","+ Eval("CommentSeqNo") + "," + Eval("UserNo") + ", \"{0}\");", Eval("LoginID")) %>'   ></asp:LinkButton>
```

Now what I want to do with 'this' button is that I want to call Bootstrap .popover() to it. So below I'm trying to get the btn's ClientID and do .popover() but red underline shows up under btn.ClientID. And I cannot use the button's class because there are several buttons that have the same class.

```
function createDiv(btn, ReplyNo, CommentSeqNo,ReportedUserNo, LoginID) {

                $('#' + '<%= btn.ClientID %>').popover({
                trigger: 'manual',
                placement: 'left',
                content: vType + vContent

             });

             $('#' + '<%= btn.ClientID %>').popover("show");
```

}

Comment: If you `console.log(btn)`  - what is it?

Comment: Is your JavaScript in an *.aspx, *.ascx, or a *.master page? If not, it may not be getting executed server-side. Aside, you don't need to use string concatenation since the ClientID is being injected server-side.

Comment: javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$MainContent$ListView1$ctrl0$btn_reportReply2',")

Comment: Also, there's some confusion here as you're referring to btn as a client-side function parameter, but calling it as a server-side control identifier. It doesn't make sense for it to be both, as the latter precludes it from being a parameter. If it needs to be a parameter, then the <%# btn.ClientID %> call would need to be in each function call, as the first parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`OnClientClick` is rendered as `onclick` on the DOM object. The `this` in that scope is the DOM object itself, so you can use `btn.id` to get the `ClientID` or simply use `$(btn)` in your function.

Here's a sample:

Markup

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1._Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function createDiv(btn) {
            $(btn).text($(btn).attr('id'));
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="List">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <div>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="thisIsMyId" Text="<%# Container.DataItem %>" runat="server" OnClientClick="createDiv(this); return false;" />
                </div>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Code behind

```
using System;
namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            List.DataSource = new string[] { "TEST1", "TEST2" };
            this.DataBind();
        }
    }
}
```